# print a print-protected PDF file

Tags: pdf, printing, pdf-reader

I have a 70+ page PDF file that is protected so it can not be printed by standard tools like Acrobat Reader etc. Is there a way that I can have this printed out?

*Preferably without GhostScript if possible, if not, GS solution is also welcome :)*

Comment: Have you tried other readers like [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/)?

Comment: no I haven't, but Foxit seems kinda "official" to me. do you think it can bypass the built-in PDF security?

Comment: the "built in security" is basically just asking nicely. Just try it.

Comment: I'm on it... will let u know

Comment: foxit can't print it out unfortunately... still secured :( take a look yourself http://www.umweltbundesamt.at/fileadmin/site/umweltthemen/chemikalien/KBU_Prirucka.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [A-PDF Restrictions Remover](http://www.a-pdf.com/faq/how-to-print-protected-pdf-acrobat.htm) or convert the pdf by uploading it [here](http://convert.neevia.com/pdfconvert/) and downloading it again. This time it won't have any restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

I dislike posting shareware as an answer as a rule, but I tested [A-PDF Restrictions Remover](http://www.a-pdf.com/faq/pdf-print-protection-remove-tools-free-download.htm) and it works.

It has a 15 day trial period.

Comment: gonna try that :)

Comment: damn it :) did not work - "Unfortunately this version of texworks is unable to print PDF document due to various technical reasons" - although I don't understand the reason for this...

Comment: maybe OS related.... i got Windows Vista....?

Comment: See edit. padding

Comment: thanx, this worked like a charm :)